# tomcat information regarding ajp-bio

Tags: tomcat

My production `tomcat` is contineously throwing the following info.

```
    [2015-01-01 09:24:45,531] INFO  - "ajp-bio-8080"-exec-141 - 
            com.example.PolicyDB - 164 - 
            select * from POLICY_SUB where POLICY_MAIN_ID = 118 order
            by  DISPLAY_ORDER
```

whats that means?

Answer (score 0):

ajp-bio-8080 is simply part of the thread name. This means that you are using the bio ajp listener on port 8080.
An application you have deployed appears to be logging out sql query text at INFO level.